# Are links to Zoom (or similar) meeting rooms acceptable in a question?

Tags: support, questions, edits, external-links

The question found here, [How do I receive emails in e-commerce website on Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63965574/how-do-i-receive-emails-in-e-commerce-website-on-laravel), contains a link to what I assume is a personal Zoom meeting room. Is this considered acceptable?

I do not find anything in the *Terms of Service* or *Acceptable Use Agreement* that explicitly forbids something like a link to Zoom, Google Chat, etc., but it seems like such a thing should be discouraged - content discussed in an external chat service obviously won't be part of the question or any answer added, so I don't see how it adds any value to the question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, they are not.

Links should only be provided as a way to add supporting material for a post.

A link to a chat or conference room of any kind, is extremely volatile and of no use for future visitors.

Those should be edited out.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, and I started to edit the question (fixing some of the other issues, too), then realized there's nothing that I know of which specifically says a user can't do that. I'd prefer to avoid an edit war, so asking here first.

Comment: @TiesonT. don't fear being involved in a drama, when you know that anyone that causes it would be effectively in the wrong side of the guidelines.

Comment: @Braiam I wouldn't say I "feared" it, I'm just... too old for that "stuff". #kidsthesedays

Comment: @TiesonT.: Stack Overflow is meant to be a repository of knowledge. The Q&A aspect is actually only the *vehicle* for building that knowledge repository. Imagine, 20 years from now, someone has a problem with receiving emails in Laravel, types his problem into Google, and lands on that question. Is the Zoom chat going to help them with their problem? If the answer is "No", the link shouldn't be in the question. If the answer is "Yes", well, actually, then the link still shouldn't be in the question, since everything necessary to solve the problem should be in the question itself.